# How would a QList containing pointers behave when passed by value

Tags: c++, qt, deep-copy, qtcore, qlist

Suppose you have QList containing pointers `QList<SomeThingCool*>` and you pass it to a method with a signature `void doCoolStuff(QList<SomeThingCool*> list)` what would the space and time implications be of such a call?

My guess is that there will be some overhead because a copy will be created of the QList object, we however do not need to do a deep copy since we are dealing with pointers.

One difference in behaviour would be that if `doCoolStuff` makes modifications to the list, the original list will remain untouched.

Comment: Do you understand COW in Qt, aka. [implicit sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html)? I did not downvote, by the way, just asking.

Comment: Never even heard of the term... I'm pretty new to Qt... But I'll take a look at that

Comment: OK, basically if you do not modify the list in the function, it is just the cost of an extra pointer space-wise. Otherwise, the list will be copied indeed. I am not sure that you need to have any worry about the time in here. I gave a +1 to compensate the downvote that came without reasoning. I do not like those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are writing is correct for generic C++, however `QList`, among some other Qt classes, is a bit special when it comes to this. It is [implicitly shared a class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/shared.html), aka. [copy-on-write (COW)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html). What does that mean, yeah?

The only addition to your explanation is that if you do not intend to modify the list inside the body of the method or function, your list be implicit shared, which means a shared data pointer will be only the extra space constraint.

If you intend to modify the list inside the function or method body, then there will be a deep copy made for the list. Naturally, your pointers will still remain shallowly copied because they are pointers.

As for the time dimension, by implicitly using this technique for this class, you spare the time spent on copying the list if you do not do any modification.